# How to automatically build a Java project using Ant and deploy it to WildFly in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, wildfly

On IntelliJ Community Edition 2023.2 IDEA, and I'm using Ant to copy and redeploy the project to a [WildFly](https://www.wildfly.org/)  server.

However, I am facing an issue, I need to manually build the project every time before copying it to WildFly.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

1. Right Click on the copy and select **Create Run Configuration**
   [image]
2. Add in Before launch the **Build** option
   [image]

I am expecting to trigger the build process automatically when I copy the project to WildFly.

Comment: Is there a reason to use ant and not Maven or some other dependency managing build tool?

Comment: The project have deferent modules some maven some are not, and on copy i want to copy changes/ redeploy  at once. That setup worked on Eclipse, but now i switched to IntelliJ